# Permanently labeling events on a stock DateListPlot, perhaps using ToolTip?

Tags: plotting, date-and-time, tooltip

I would like to add notes to specific days on a DateListPlot of a stock price, and have them always be visible (not just on mouseover). So far I've got how to add a tooltip to a specific day, but not sure how to get it to remain always visible, or how to get it rotated 90 degrees, or how to make days with no tooltip appear without the red dot, or how to add a tooltip using the date instead of the index (instead of stock[[3]]=ToolTip... Id like to do stock[ where date = {2003,12,29} ] if that is possible ). Thank you for any suggestions.

```
stock = {{{2003, 12, 24}, 1094.04}, {{2003, 12, 26}, 1095.89}, {{2003, 12, 29}, 1109.47}, {{2003, 12, 30}, 1109.64}, {{2003, 12, 31}, 1111.92}, {{2004, 1, 2}, 1108.47}, {{2004, 1, 5}, 1122.21}}; 

stock[[3]] = Tooltip[stock[[3]], Rotate["Earnings were released lower than expected", 90], TooltipStyle -> {Background -> White, CellFrameColor -> Blue, CellFrame -> 0}];

stock[[5]] = Tooltip[stock[[5]], Rotate["Article appeared on new product launch", 90], TooltipStyle -> {Background -> White, CellFrameColor -> Blue, CellFrame -> 0}];

DateListPlot[stock, PlotMarkers -> {Style[\[Bullet], Red], 20}]
```

Comment: In your code use `90 Degree` instead `90` to place tooltips vertically. But if you want they remain always visible use `Text` in `Epilog` to `DateListPlot` and do not redefine points: `DateListPlot[stock, PlotMarkers -> {Style[\[Bullet], Red], 20}, Epilog -> {Text["Earnings were released\n lower than expected", stock[[3]], {-1, 0}, {0, 1}]}, PlotRangePadding -> {{Automatic, Automatic}, {Automatic, Scaled[0.3]}}]`. Your labels are very long, so I added `\n` to break a string and set manually `PlotRangePadding`.

Comment: Consider to shorten texts or use just simple labels 1, 2, ... and put description in caption or main text of your document.

Comment: See also `Callout` command in Help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Too long for a comment... Example of using `Callout`:

```
stock = {{{2003, 12, 24}, 1094.04}, {{2003, 12, 26}, 1095.89}, 
Callout[{{2003, 12, 29}, 1109.47}, 
"Earnings were released\n lower than expected", Above, 
CalloutMarker -> "Circle", Appearance -> "Leader", 
LeaderSize -> 30], {{2003, 12, 30}, 1109.64}, 
Callout[{{2003, 12, 31}, 1111.92}, 
"Article appeared\n on new product launch", Below, 
CalloutMarker -> "Box", Appearance -> "Leader", LeaderSize -> 30, 
Background -> None], {{2004, 1, 2}, 1108.47}, {{2004, 1, 5}, 
1122.21}};
DateListPlot[stock]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you Alx, both of those perfectly fit the bill. Many thanks!

Comment: Thank you for accepting answer! And welcome to Mathematica SE!